# 13.10 and Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Trying to get my Intel and Nvida GPUs to run on Xubuntu 13.10. (Worked with 12.10)

```
[  230.154527] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load 
module "glamoregl" (module does not exist, 0)

[  230.154698] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I used this guide (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Hybrid-Grafikkarten/Bumblebee)
Now I'm stuck with a screen resolution of 800x600 and optirun throws these error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problems with my laptop I fixed it by doing:

```
sudo lspci | grep NVIDIA
```

You should get something like:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev ff)
```

01:00.0 is the part you will need, now go to your bumblebee config

```
sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

And just after VendorName type:

```
BusID "PCI:01:00.0"
```

(Or whatever your numbers are)

Hope this helped :)